# Kafka _consumer_offsets produced records consistency

Tags: apache-kafka

Was wondering how are produced exactly the records whe find in the internal topic _consumer_offsets in term of consistency.

I know that the default min isr for this topic is  1 and replication factor is 3.
I know that when our consumer is committing, records are added to this topic.. But how exactly? Is it a internal producer that use acks=all or whatever?
If I want to increase reads consistency, does it make sense to increase the _consumer_offsets min isr? How can I be sure if the producing of records in this topic will be acks=all?

Regards

Yannick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each consumer group a broker is elected as GroupCoordinator. When a consumer commits its offset it will send a OffsetCommitRequest to its GroupCoordinator.

This is actually, the GroupCoordinator whish is responsible to produce messages into the internal `__consumer_offsets` topic.

The acknowlegment is configured by the broker property: `offsets.commit.required.acks`.
By default, this propoerty is set to -1 (i.e acks=all).